# C++ Template Specialization Compilation

Tags: c++, dll, templates, compilation, specialization

I'm going to outline my problem in detail to explain what I'm trying to achieve, the question is in the last paragraph if you wish to ignore the details of my problem.

I have a problem with a class design in which I wish to pass a value of any type into `push()` and `pop()` functions which will convert the value passed into a string representation that will be appended to a string inside the class, effectively creating a stream of data. The reverse will occur for `pop()`, taking the stream and converting several bytes at the front of the stream back into a specified type.

Making `push()` and `pop()` templates tied with `stringstream` is an obvious solution. However, I wish to use this functionality inside a DLL in which I can change the way the string is stored (encryption or compression, for example) without recompilation of clients. A template of type `T` would need to be recompiled if the algorithm changes.

My next idea was to just use functions such as `pushByte()`, `pushInt()`, `popByte()`, `popInt()` etc. This would allow me to change the implementation without recompilation of clients, since they rely only on a static interface. This would be fine. However, it isn't so flexible. If a value was changed from a byte to a short, for example, all instances of pushByte() corresponding to that value would need to be changed to `pushShort()`, similarly for `popByte()` to `popShort()`. Overloading `pop()` and `push()` to combat this would cause conflictions in types (causing explicit casting, which would end up causing the same problem anyway).

With the above ideas, I could create a working class. However, I wondered how specialized templates are compiled. If I created `push<byte>()` and `push<short>()`, it would be a type specific overload, and the change from byte to short would automatically switch the template used, which would be ideal.

Now, my question is, if I used specialized templates only to simulate this kind of overloading (without a template of type `T`), would all specializations compile into my DLL allowing me to dispatch a new implementation without client recompilation? Or are specialized templates selected or dropped in the same way as a template of type `T` at client compilation time?

Comment: Some pointers to template specialization and overloading from Herb Sutter. http://gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm

Comment: Why would overloads require explicit casting it the user switches types?

Comment: If I passed a short into a function overloaded with push(byte), push(short) and push(int), wouldn't this cause confliction in which function to choose from push(short) and push(int)? A short can be passed into either and be valid.

Comment: No problem there, `push(short)` is the better match. By the way, you can use back-ticks for inline code - see my edit.

Comment: @Charlie Wilkinson: Most compilers choose the declared type if multiple possibilites are given. But some (like VS i believe) require explicit casting by the caller then.

Comment: @thats: I don't have VC running now, but i can't remember a case where they messed overload resolution that much up (lets just not think about VC6).

Comment: I noticed the edit, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't *just* have specialized templates without a base template to specialize. It's just not allowed. You have to start with a template, then you can provide specializations of it.

You can explicitly instantiate a template over an arbitrary set of types, and have all those instantiations compiled into your DLL, but I'm not sure this will really accomplish much for you. Ultimately, templates are basically a compile-time form of polymorphism, and you seem to need (at least a limited form of) run-time polymorphism.

I'd probably just use overloading. The problem that I'd guess you're talking about arises with something on the order of:

```
int a;
byte b;

a = pop();
b = pop();
```

Where you'd basically just be overloading `pop` on the return type (which, as we all know, isn't allowed). I'd avoid that pretty simply -- instead of returning the value, pass a reference to the value to be modified:

```
int a;
byte b;

pop(a);
pop(b);
```

This not only lets overload resolution work, but at least to me looks cleaner as well (though maybe I've just written too much assembly language, so I'm accustomed to things like "pop ax").

Comment: And if you want `const` initializations you can still provide a wrapper: `template<class T> T pop_it() { T t; pop(t); return t; }` ... or use a dummy parameter: `a = pop(int());` :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have 2 opposing factors:

1. You want your clients to be able to push/pop/etc. every numeric type. Templates seem like a natural solution, but this is at odds with a consistent (only needs to be compiled once) implementation.
2. You don't want your clients to have to recompile when you change implementation aspects. The [pimpl idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pimpl_idiom) seems like a natural solution, but this is at odds with a generic (works with any type) implementation.

From your description, it sounds like you only care about numeric types, not arbitrary T's. You can declare specializations of your template for each of them explicitly in a header file, and define them in a source file, and clients will use the specializations you've defined rather than compiling their own. The specializations are a form of compile time polymorphism. Now you can combine it with runtime polymorphism -- implement the specializations in terms of an implementation class that is type agnostic. Your implementation class could use [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/variant.html) to do this since you know the range of possible T's ahead of time (`boost::variant<int, short, long, ...>`). If boost isn't an option for you, you can come up with a similar scheme yourself so long as you have a finite number of Ts you care about.